# How to write where condition for column having decimal datatype in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I have a date column which is of type "PIC S9(7) COMP-3" in IBM DB2/AS400.
When I put these values in SQL Server, my data type of column made changed as "decimal(7,0)".This is just to making DB2 datatype similar to SQL Server.

Now, I would like to find if there is any "space" or "numeric" in this particular date column.

The date column is like this:

```
 DATE
-------
4040404
       (a space)
404040
2020202
       (a space)
202020
```

In where condition like this gives error:
      "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

```
 Select ID, DATE 
 from Table1
 Where DATE = ''
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: if your column is a decimal(7,0) it can not have a space there, it should be a null.

Answer (score 0):

Because a space is occurring in the column, data type should default to varchar.

Explicitly convert the column (to avoid data type errors) to varchar and then check for floating spaces or numbers using wildcards. E.g.
`where Convert(varchar, Column_Date) like '%[ ]%'` or 
`where Convert(varchar, Column_Date) like '%[0-9]%'` depending on what you want to filter out.